# Is there exist such $f$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Is there exist an $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ where $\sup f(X)= +\infty$ and $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X$ where X is bounded? I think there should not be existing such $f$ as the change of the value of $f$ too quick

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If $\sup f(X)=\infty$, then $f$ is not bounded.

Comment: See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254224/continuity-and-boundedness/254316#254316

Comment: @AlexYoucis I think (s)he probably means $X$ a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, not $f$ bounded

Answer (score 2):

As others have said there is no such $f$ when $X\subset{\mathbb R}$. But in an arbitrary metric space $X$ you may have such $f$'s. Here is an example:

Let $X:={\mathbb R}$ and provide $X$ with the metric $$d(x,y):={|x-y|\over 1+|x-y|}\ .$$
Then all distances in $X$ are $<1$, so $X$ is "bounded". But for $|x-y|\ll 1$ the new distance is pretty much the usual one. It follows that the unbounded function
$$f(x):=\log\bigl(1+|x|\bigr)$$ 
is locally Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $1$, whence uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, as per Deven Ware's comment, you mean that $X$ is bounded. Then, what you say is true. Namely, since $f$ is uniformly continuous and $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, it's a common fact that you can extend $f$ to a map $\widetilde{f}:\overline{X}\to\mathbb{R}$ by merely defining $\widetilde{f}(x)=\lim f(x_n)$ where $x_n$ is a sequence in $X$ converging to $x$. But, then $\widetilde{f}$ is continuous on the bounded and closed set $\overline{X}$, and thus $\widetilde{f}$ and thus $f$ is bounded.

Comment: So do you mean that if $X$ bounded and $f$ is uniformly continuous then $f$ must be convergent hence impossible equal to $+\infty$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. What I'm saying is that you are correct. Any uniformly continuous real function on a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded (of course, more is true if you look closely at my proof).

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ is bounded there exists some diameter $d \geq 0$ such that $|x - y| \leq d$ for all $x, y \in X$.  Let $x_0, x_1, \dotsc$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $f(x_{n+1}) \geq f(x_n) + 1$.  Then $|f(x_a) - f(x_b)| \geq 1$ for all indices $a\neq b$.  Take some integer $N > 0$.  Then there are indices $a, b \leq N$, $a \neq b$ such that $|x_a - x_b| \leq \tfrac{d}{N}$.  Since $N$ can be chosen arbitrarily large, $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $X$.